# Cannot get gcal to load

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to get my gcal to load, but it won't and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/gcal.js"></script> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/hq@eschamp.com/public/basic/'
        }
    });
});
```

The calendar loads fine, but I see no events on it.  You can see it here for an example: http://www.eschamp.com/index.php/schedule

Looking in the error console it seems to load fine.  If I try a different gcal url it complains, so it seems to be loading proper.  So I am not sure what's up.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Man I figured this would be a quick one to solve, bummer : (

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/hq@eschamp.com/public/basic/'
```

if you don't want to specify any other options. You only need to use `url:` if you want to set other calendar options like `className`

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the calendar is not set to public?
I guess that would make the URL valid but the events not visible.
Would you give it a try?